# Why is my for loop only printing the first if statement repeatedly?

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I am trying to create a list representing a chess board. I have this code for it:

```
#possible list items
EMPTY = "-"
ROOK = "ROOK"
KNIGHT = "KNIGHT"
BISHOP = "BISHOP"
QUEEN = "QUEEN"
KING = "KING"
PAWN = "PAWN"
board = []

royal_row = [] #list for row containing king

pawn_row = []#list for pawn row

row = [] #generic row

#setting the board
for i in range(8):
    if i == 0 or 7:
        royal_row = [ROOK,KNIGHT,BISHOP,QUEEN,KING,BISHOP,KNIGHT,ROOK]
        board.append(royal_row)
        
    elif i == 1 or 6:
        pawn_row = [PAWN for i in range(8)]
        board.append(pawn_row)
        
    else: 
        row = [EMPTY for i in range(8)]
        board.append(row)

for i in range(8):
    print(board[i], end = "\n")
```

When I run this code it just prints:

```
['ROOK', 'KNIGHT', 'BISHOP', 'QUEEN', 'KING', 'BISHOP', 'KNIGHT', 'ROOK']

['ROOK', 'KNIGHT', 'BISHOP', 'QUEEN', 'KING', 'BISHOP', 'KNIGHT', 'ROOK']

['ROOK', 'KNIGHT', 'BISHOP', 'QUEEN', 'KING', 'BISHOP', 'KNIGHT', 'ROOK']

['ROOK', 'KNIGHT', 'BISHOP', 'QUEEN', 'KING', 'BISHOP', 'KNIGHT', 'ROOK']

['ROOK', 'KNIGHT', 'BISHOP', 'QUEEN', 'KING', 'BISHOP', 'KNIGHT', 'ROOK']

['ROOK', 'KNIGHT', 'BISHOP', 'QUEEN', 'KING', 'BISHOP', 'KNIGHT', 'ROOK']

['ROOK', 'KNIGHT', 'BISHOP', 'QUEEN', 'KING', 'BISHOP', 'KNIGHT', 'ROOK']

['ROOK', 'KNIGHT', 'BISHOP', 'QUEEN', 'KING', 'BISHOP', 'KNIGHT', 'ROOK']
```

my expected output is:

```
['ROOK', 'KNIGHT', 'BISHOP', 'QUEEN', 'KING', 'BISHOP', 'KNIGHT', 'ROOK']

['PAWN', 'PAWN', 'PAWN', 'PAWN', 'PAWN', 'PAWN', 'PAWN', 'PAWN']

['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']

['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']

['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']

['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']

['PAWN', 'PAWN', 'PAWN', 'PAWN', 'PAWN', 'PAWN', 'PAWN', 'PAWN']

['ROOK', 'KNIGHT', 'BISHOP', 'QUEEN', 'KING', 'BISHOP', 'KNIGHT', 'ROOK']
```

If I separate the 1, 0, 6, and 7 to their own elif clause then it prints correctly but I want to understand why the original code doesn't

Comment: use in:  `if i in [0,7]:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You decide to change in the if's and put:
`i == 0 or i == 7`
and `i == 1 or i == 6`

```
#possible list items
EMPTY = "-"
ROOK = "ROOK"
KNIGHT = "KNIGHT"
BISHOP = "BISHOP"
QUEEN = "QUEEN"
KING = "KING"
PAWN = "PAWN"
board = []

royal_row = [] #list for row containing king

pawn_row = []#list for pawn row

row = [] #generic row

#setting the board
for i in range(8):
    if i == 0 or i == 7:
        royal_row = [ROOK,KNIGHT,BISHOP,QUEEN,KING,BISHOP,KNIGHT,ROOK]
        board.append(royal_row)

    elif i == 1 or i == 6:
        pawn_row = [PAWN for i in range(8)]
        board.append(pawn_row)

    else:
        row = [EMPTY for i in range(8)]
        board.append(row)

for i in range(8):
    print(board[i], end = "\n")
```

Comment: Thanks !I did that and it fixed the issue.
Do you know why writing it the way I originally did would cause that line to repeat itself?

Comment: @Binomial_Gnome I wrote it at the beginning. before the code. When you did the if you didn't put equality for both numbers.
You have to do: `if i == 0 or i == 7` and also `elif i == 1 or i == 6`

Answer (score 0):

`if i == 0 or 7:`

This statement is essentially the below

`if i == 0 or 7 != 0`

So, because 7 is always greater than 1, it is always true.

To fix this, try the following instead

`if i == 1 or i == 7`

Comment: The use of `or 7` is not equivalent to `or 7 >=1`.

Comment: Oops, you're right. It's just non-zero isn't it. My bad

Comment: It's not `or 7 != 1` either.

Comment: Yeah sorry, changed the >= but not the number. That's right now, right?

Comment: Yup, it's good now.